# How do I run multiple commands together in the background?

Tags: bash, shell, zsh, background-process

I know I can run a program in the background using `&`.

```
command &
```

However, I want to run multiple commands, and `cd` into a different directory while they are running.
The multiple commands will still rely on the directory I was previously in.

I've tried the following, but it only runs the last command in the background:

```
command1 && command2 &
```

Doing this gives a parse error:

```
command1 & && command2 &
```

It's important that `command1` finishes before `command2`,
 so I don't think the following would guarantee that:

```
 command1 &; command2 &;
```

I'm not tied to any specific shell.

Comment: Note that `;` isn't needed after `&`, it can separate commands itself: `command1 & command2`.

Comment: @choroba Not just not needed, it's a syntax error (in bash and most other shells): there needs to be a command before `;`

Comment: If you need to do that in a bash script, use the method suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62832235/1423806

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`(command1; command2)&` - should do it, works in bash.

This creates a subshell (the two parenthesis) and runs the whole subshell in the background.

Comment: Or `{ command1; command2; } &` — running a command in the background already creates a subshell so using `(…)` instead of `{ … }` is redundant.